# Can I make this Javascript code shorter?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I'm just starting programming, can I make this code shorter? Maybe with an array? Thanks.

```
function createDragName1(){
    var firstName;
    var random1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*17)+0);
    var name1 = "va";
    var name2 = "tuul";

    switch(random1){
        case 0:
            firstName = name1;
            break;
        case 1:
            firstName = name2;
            break;
        default:
            firstName = "Error";
    }

    var testingName = firstName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+firstName.substring(1,6);

    return(testingName);

}
```

Comment: write an unit test and then try to refactor it

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 17? Do you really want to return "Error" over 88% of the time?

Comment: It's not terribly long. Why do you need to make it shorter?

Comment: Let me count for you: `+0`, 4 extra `var` statements, unnecessary temporary variable, parentheses around `return`, `Math.random`, `default` switch case that could be coded with a default value, yes, you can make it shorter.

Comment: This isn't code review...?

Comment: http://javascriptcompressor.com/

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com or http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use a map:

```
function createDragName1(){
    var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 17), // [0, 17)
    names = ['Va', 'Tuul']; // title cased names

    return names[random1] || 'Error';
}
```

The expression `names[random1] || 'Error'` returns a name if `0 <= random1 < names.length` and `'Error'` otherwise.

I've also removed the title case logic by manually title casing `names`.

Btw, the random number will in most cases be outside of the desired range, so you will return `Error` an awful many times.

Comment: Put the array inline in the return statement and it's even shorter ;)

Comment: @plalx Doing that would degrade the code readability though :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to return either "Va" or "Tuul" with equal probability, and don't really want to return "Error":

```
function createDragName1() {
    return Math.random() < 0.5 ? "Va" : "Tuul";
}
```

However, if you do want the original behavior:

```
function createDragName1() {
    var rand = 17 * Math.random();
    return rand < 1 ? "Va" : rand < 2 ? "Tuul" : "Error";
}
```

A general method for picking a random name out of an array is:

```
var array = ["Va", "Tuul"];
var randomElement = array[0 | (array.length * Math.random())];
```

(The weird notation `0 | x` evaluates to the integer part of `x` because the bitwise `|` operator converts arguments to integer if necessary.) If you want an expanded range:

```
var array = ["Va", "Tuul"];
var randomElementOrError = array[0 | (17 * Math.random())] || "Error";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function createDragName1(){

    var random1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*17)+0);
    var firstName = ["va","tuul"][random1];
    if(!firstName){
       firstName = 'Error';
    }

    var testingName = firstName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+firstName.substr(1);

    return(testingName);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make it much shorter than:

```
function createDragName1() {
    return ['Va', 'Tuul'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 17)] || 'Error';
}
```